# How do I get my java program written with NetBeans to compile with javac?

Tags: netbeans, javac

I have two java files. They run fine in NetBeans, but I have to compile them in javac, and run them on a unix machine since I'm connecting to a database on my school's server.

I've been searching online but everything is too specific, and I'm not too familiar with NetBeans.

What I'm doing is copying those two java files, and a .form file to a directory on my school's server, and then try to compile the two java files using javac. However, I'm assuming that it doesn't compile because it's missing all the information from the .form file?

I'm getting 100 errors when compiling the one of the java files, and they look something like this:

> CARTSJFrame.java:380: package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist
>                          .add(jPanel9, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_                    SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLay

My guess was that it has something to do with the .form file that I can see in my NetBeans project directory.

I've looked at previous questions about this but still haven't been able to figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into compilation errors because NetBeans includes a jar in your project's classpath automagically when you compile and run the project.

NetBeans uses the dot-form file to help it generate code for the layout.  It is not used at compilation time.

There are a couple strategies that you can follow to resolve this problem:

1. Get the jar that has the classes...
   http://www.findjar.com/jar/net.java.dev.swing-layout/jars/swing-layout-1.0.1.jar.html;jsessionid=252692AC0FBE9421C9436A748744ACED... and include that jar in your
   classpath at compile and runtime.
2. Convert the code in your project to
   use the javax.swing.GroupLayout. 
   This is a 'standard part' of Java SE 6.  This [SO answer covers how to convert between
   org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout and
   javax.swing.GroupLayout in
   NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880888/javax-swing-grouplayout-not-exist-in-jdk-1-5).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that javac doesn't know where to find that library.

A typical Java project uses many libraries. Netbeans uses a folder "lib" to store those libraries and also some configuration files to automatically set the classpath. The classpath is a environment variable that Javac uses to 'know' where are the libraries.

When you use javac to compile the java files you need to provide the CLASSPATH variable first. Write all you dependencies.

An example:

Project/compile_all.sh

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:"lib/jopt-simple-3.2.jar":"lib/commons-io-2.0.jar"

javac src/*.java
```

Now you just need to run

```
sh compile_all.sh
```

And it compiles all you .java files